# Google Chrome Doesn't Allow Height on iframe for YouTube

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

For some reason my YouTube videos I have embedded on my website doesn't have a height in Chrome, Firefox, and I'm assuming IE too. It works just fine in Safari oddly enough. My website is dynamic so I have the width setup as a percentage. I have tried http://, https://, //www for the src on the video, doesn't do anything. Also tried height as auto, setup a percentage for height and that doesn't work either.

```css
.video-container {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 0;
  margin-bottom: -60px;
  text-align: center;
}
.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
  position: center;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/yGqXk5AHSRg" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to add my webpages are running as php with html code, not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works (I found the page you copied those styles from, and they work for me):

https://jsfiddle.net/tobyl/0vx4upa1/

```
.video-container {
    position:relative;
      padding-bottom:56.25%;
      padding-top:30px;
      height:0;
      overflow:hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
    position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
}
```